# What are the available output formats for writeStream in Spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Consider a generic `writeStream` invocation - with the typical *"console"* output format:

```
out.writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()
```

What are the alternatives?  I noticed actually that the *default* is `parquet`:

In `DataStreamWriter`:

```
  /**
   * Specifies the underlying output data source.
   *
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  def format(source: String): DataStreamWriter[T] = {
    this.source = source
    this
  }

  private var source: String = df.sparkSession.sessionState.conf.defaultDataSourceName
```

In `SQLConf`:

```
  def defaultDataSourceName: String = getConf(DEFAULT_DATA_SOURCE_NAME)

  val DEFAULT_DATA_SOURCE_NAME = buildConf("spark.sql.sources.default")
    .doc("The default data source to use in input/output.")
    .stringConf
    .createWithDefault("parquet")
```

But then how is the *path* for the parquet file specified? What are the other formats supported and what options do they have/require?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the official spark documentation for the same: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks

As of spark 2.4.1, five formats are supported out of the box:

- File sink
- Kafka sink
- Foreach sink
- Console sink
- Memory sink

On top of that one can also implement her custom sink by extending `Sink` API of Spark: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Sink.scala

Answer (score 2):

I found one reference: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/89282/structured-streaming-writestream-append-to-file.html

It seems that `option("path",path)` can be used:

[image]